# Need a PDF printer that allows multiple printers with one install

Tags: print-to-pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PDF printer without user intervention](https://superuser.com/questions/103855/pdf-printer-without-user-intervention)

I know there are tons of PDF printer recommendations on this site (I believe I have even answered one) however I need one that allows you to create multiple PDF printers.

Let me give you guys a run down of the scenario since this may seem like an odd request...

- We have virtual printer software that redirects printers from our print server to our terminal servers. It keeps things consistent across all terminal servers so we can load balance and not have to reassign printers to each user on each server, it also controls the users desktops, and allows us to use 32 bit drivers on our 64 bit terminal servers (Zebra zm400's don't have 64 bit drivers). Our [software](http://www.tricerat.com/) (if it matters...)
- For accountability reasons we want to keep archive copies of each print job on our Array in PDF form so we can pull documents and tell users, "yes your document printed, here's our copy."
- We decided to go with [Multiprint](http://www.edocfile.com/MultiPrint.htm) or something similar to print one copy to the appropriate printer, one copy to a PDF printer, save the .PRN file so we can reprocess, and email the user or a group (yes, these are mission critical documents).

I have tried PDF creator and it works perfectly on the print server. However it doesn't work through Tricerat's software on our terminal servers. I have tested it as a multiprint printer and as just a standard PDF printer.... The strange thing is users use the redirected screwdrivers (our vendors version of RDP redirect) PDF printers all the time. They use DoPDF, Cutewriter, and Primo and they all print fine, but only allow for one PDF printer at a time and give a save prompt (no good). We need one like PDF creator that has an autosave function and allows you to create multiple printers, paid software is perfectly fine in this instance.

Comment: I don't know that they're quite close enough to be duplicates.  You're asking a totally different, very valid question here, in addition to the autosave one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [Bullzip](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php) (and also the paid version, [BioPDF](http://www.biopdf.com/)) support installing multiple virtual printers.  I haven't tested this myself.

As far as autosave, I haven't played with it in a while but I'm fairly sure you can configure it to bypass essentially all prompts.

Comment: I will have to test bullzip... so far it the features look good. I'll have to test to tomorrow though I just got pulled away on another issue...

Comment: I use Bullzip all the time. Never set up more than 1 PDF printer, but it says it can handle it. Using just 1 works beautifully. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mistiry - Yeah, Bullzip is pretty good. I didn't want to intentionally inflate it since I don't actually use the functionality Kyle's asking about, but it's pretty awesome.

Comment: I love Bullzip, but has anyone figured out how to install multiple print drivers?